# How to print character array in reverse order of C program

Tags: c, arrays, decimal, converters, radix

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 25

int main (void)
{

        int d, b, c;

        printf(" Enter an integer and press 'enter':\n");
        scanf("%d" , &d);
        printf(" Enter the desired base and press 'enter':\n");
        scanf("%d" , &b);

        if (b < 2) {

                printf(" Your base is to low! \n")
        } else {

                while (d != 0) {

                        int radix;
                        radix = d % b;
                        d = d / b;
                        char basechars[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

                        printf("%c" , basechards[radix]);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

This Program prompts the user for a decimal and a base to convert that    decimal to the base that has been chosen. The conversion is however printed in reverse order and I need it to print regular. Example: Entered: 112, then entered 16, result is 07 rather than 70.

Comment: Store the digits in array instead of printing them, and then print the array in reverse.

Comment: As a bit of a random comment, a base of 1 is technically valid: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system

Comment: Well, if being picky, a base above 16 is valid as well, and won't be handled properly by this program (undefined behavior, actually).

Comment: @Jon how would I mark off every 5th with a horizontal strike-through? Is that a wierd kind of binary?

Comment: @WeatherVane I am more concerned about `0` representation..

Comment: @EugeneSh. if your comment relates to Jon's, then no marks at all ;-)

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, but then people will see zeros everywhere :)

Comment: @EugeneSh `0` is a new-fangled thing. It didn't use to exist at all, perhaps it still doesn't.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, but in any positional notation based system it has to present (as a placeholder for certain positions, which hold nothing). But well, you can say that unary is not position based.

Comment: We could stray onto negative notation, say I have `-1` apples that means you owe me an apple, but if I have `-0` apples you owe me none, whereas if I have `0` apples, I don't owe you any. Semantics? Now, what does it mean if I have *`i`* apples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store each digit in an array:

```
} else {
    char arr[32];
    int counter = 0;
    while (d != 0) {
        int radix;
        radix = d % b;
        d = d / b;
        char basechars[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        arr[counter++] = basechars[radix];
    }
    if (counter == 0)
        arr[counter++] = '0';
    arr[counter++] = '\0';
    print_rev(arr);
    printf("\n");
}
```

and then print the string using a recursive function (it will reverse the output):

```
void print_rev(const char *s)
{
    if (*s) {
        print_rev(s + 1);
        printf("%c", *s);
    }
}
```

or directly:

```
} else {
    char arr[32];
    int counter = 0;
    while (d != 0) {
        int radix;
        radix = d % b;
        d = d / b;
        char basechars[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        arr[counter++] = basechars[radix];
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
        printf("0");
    else {
        while (counter--)
            printf("%c", arr[counter]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Suggest reviewing for `d == 0`.

Comment: BTW: Changing `while (d != 0) { ...}` to `do { ... } while (d != 0);` would handle the `d==0` case without adding `if (counter == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

This version does dynamic memory allocation so that you don't have to specify how long the converted string has to be beforehand.

The numbers can be as large as you please, especially important in binary conversion. I also put a check for base 16, which is the upper limit.

```
int main (void)
{

        int d, b, c, i = 1;
        char *converted = malloc(i);
        printf(" Enter an integer and press 'enter':\n");
        scanf("%d" , &d);
        printf(" Enter the desired base and press 'enter':\n");
        scanf("%d" , &b);

        if (b < 2) {

                printf(" Your base is to low! \n");
                return 1;

        } else if (b > 16) {

                printf(" Your base is to high! \n");
                return 1;

        } else {

                while (d != 0) {

                        int radix;
                        radix = d % b;
                        d = d / b;
                        char basechars[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
                        converted = realloc(converted, i++);
                        *(converted +i - 1) = basechars[radix];

                }
        }
    i--;
    while(i != 0) {
        printf("%c", converted[i]);
        --i;
    }
    free(converted);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes but you have not addressed the @EugeneSh. comment above, about `base > 16`. You could have `char basechars[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";` and the test `if (b < 2 || b > 36)`

Comment: yeah that is right, I just assumed he goes until base 16, he has to make sure an error message displays if the user chooses a base higher than 16

Comment: And I think this is suspicious `converted = realloc(converted, i++);` seeing as that is the same memory you originally allocated.

Comment: test it, it works, it is the same memory the first time (1), and then it goes 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., I also put a check for base 16

Comment: You use a sledgehammer to crack a nut. You know how many binary digits there can be in an `int` by doing `char converted [sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT + 1];`

Comment: well yes but it is only for binary digits, but you are right that you can calculate how much space is needed for a particular base after the user selects a base, that would be the better way.

Comment: I am not expecting him to come back though, if you look at his profile, he seems to ask questions and never even accept an answer, the question was meaningless anyway, how to reverse printing, I just answered it because I was in the mood. but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That's OK, you can assign the maximum `char[]` array possible *before* the base is even entered. It's cheap.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reversing the array is the most straightforward way.
2. Use the limit.h macro LONG_BIT to know the maximum needed characters to store.  This sizes your array.
3. I'm also checking the base for the upper limit of 16.
4. Build the array, then print it.  Note it handles 0 just fine.
5. You also forgot negative numbers.

   ```
   } else if (b > 16) {
       printf(" Your base is too high! \n");
   } else {
       const char basechars[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

       char arr[LONG_BIT];  // d is an integer, so LONG_BIT holds
                    // enough characters for a binary representation.
       int counter = 0;
       int negative_flag = 0;

       if (d < 0) {
           d = -d;
           negative_flag = 1;
       }

       do {
           int digit = d % b;
           d = d / b;

           arr[counter++] = basechars[digit];
        } while (d != 0);

        if (negative_flag) {
           printf ("-");
        }

        while (counter--) {
            printf ("%c", arr[counter]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Offer a recursive approach.

Determine if additional `chars` need to be printed from the more significant digits, recursively call the helper function and *then* print the numbers least significant digit.

Code should take care to handle "0" as a valid input.  The below uses negative values to well handle `INT_MIN`.

```
static void PrintDigits(int x, int base) {
  static const char basechars[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  if (x <= -base) {
    PrintDigits(x/base, base);
  }
  putchar(basechars[-(x%base)]);
}

void PrintInt(int x, int base) {
  if (base < 2 || base > 16) {
    printf(" Your base is out of range! \n");
  } else {
    if (x < 0) putchar('-');
    else x = -x;
    PrintDigits(x, base);
  }
  putchar('\n');
}

int main(void) {
  PrintInt(65535, 16);
  PrintInt(65535, 10);
  PrintInt(65535, 2);
  PrintInt(INT_MAX, 10);
  PrintInt(0, 10);
  PrintInt(-1, 16);
  PrintInt(INT_MIN, 10);

  int d, b;
  printf(" Enter an integer and press 'enter':\n");
  scanf("%d" , &d);
  printf(" Enter the desired base and press 'enter':\n");
  scanf("%d" , &b);
  PrintInt(d, b);
  return 0;
}
```

> FFFF
>   65535
>   1111111111111111
>   2147483647
>   0
>   -1
>   -2147483648

Even with base 2, recursion depth would be no more than the bit width of `int`.